# Microsoft Outlook 365 - Home Ribbon - Stop labels from showing and hiding when changing messages

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, ribbon

I am using the Microsoft 365 version of Outlook (Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise, VErsion 2310, Build 16924.20150 Click-to-run, Current Channel) on a Windows 11 computer.

I notice that depending on the message that I select, the Delete section of the Home Ribbon displays or hides labels for the "Ignore", "Clean Up" and "Junk" buttons.
[image: MS OUTLOOK 365 Ribbon shows Ignore, Clean Up and Junk Labels]
[image: MS OUTLOOK 365 Ribbon hides Ignore, Clean Up and Junk Labels]

I am not changing the size of the window and there is empty space at the end of my ribbon.

How can I prevent this from happening? As I start clicking delete to delete a bunch of messages then all of a sudden it prompts me if I want to ignore a conversation, which I do not want to do. Ideal situation is to always have either the labels show all the time or hidden all the time.

Thank you for your guidance on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot change this. The items you show (Ignore, cleanup, Junk) are built into the Ribbon and are context sensitive depending on which Ribbon button you press.

If you get a lot of one type of message, you can filter into or delete if you do not need the messages using Outlook Rules to take effect before reading.

I just ignore these things as they do not impede my workflow.

Comment: The only issue is that if I am deleting a lot of messages (i.e. "system spam" notifications that jobs were ran) and I keep clicking the delete button but it keeps moving. This did not happen in the prior version of Outlook. So it is very frustrating.

Comment: Perhaps use a Rule to move such messages to a folder or delete before being read. That would definitely help with the ribbon

Answer (score 0):

From the version information you provided, it is not the latest version, it is recommended that you upgrade Outlook to the latest to see if there is the same problem.

Go to File > Office Account > Update Now

Comment: I have to see if I’m able to as the device is managed by our it team